Why is the order of $dz$ on Riemann sphere at $\infty$ equal to $-2$?
The setting is as follows: We consider $X= \mathbb{C}_\infty$, the Riemann sphere with coordinate $z$ on $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\omega = dz$ (this is a $1$-form).
On page 131 of Rick Miranda's book "Algebraic Curves and Riemann surfaces" it says that

Then $\operatorname{div}(\omega) = -2 \cdot \infty$, since $\omega$ has no zeroes, and has a double pole at $\infty$.

The order of $\omega = dz$ is the order of the factor infront of $dz$, which in this case is $1$. So why does the constant function $1$ have a pole of order $2$ at infinity?

The rational function $z$ doesn't give a local coordinate at $\infty$. To find the order of the rational 1-form $dz$ at $\infty$ you need to write it in terms of a coordinate that is defined at $\infty$, e.g $y=1/z$. What is the order of $dz = d(1/y)$ at $\infty$, i.e. $y=0$?

Oh, so I have to compute the order of $1/y^2$ at $y=0$! And that is $-2$. Thanks.
